# Regex if statement problems

Tags: c#, regex, if-statement

First post so I am sorry if I do not provide enough information, however, I will try my best. Also, it is probably wise to note I have bare minimal knowledge of this, I know basically what this code does and that is it.

In short I am a member or a simulation game community which mainly consists of cruising around running from/being the police. the game logs all chat messages as they are sent straight to a .txt file and this code searches said chatlog for one of the parameters listed in the code below and if it matches one it will play the corresponding "beep".

The first two work however the third one i have some struggles with and was wondering if anyone here could help me understand. One of the features these "cops" have is a speed gun, which shows results in-game like so:

`user clocked @ 105kph/ 65mph• ignored` *

`user clocked @ 138kph/ 86mph•` **

* this is below the speed limit

** this is above the speed limit

however in the chatlog they appear like this:

```
user ^Lclocked @ 138kph/ 86mph•

user ^Lclocked @ 63kph/ 39mph•^L ignored
```

i have tried using varied wildcards(assuming they work) and writing the code in both fashions like so:

```
Regex expspeeding = new Regex(@"mph• ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Regex expspeeding = new Regex(@"#mph•^L ignored ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

but it simply does not work.

Below is the main bulk of what I have, please if anyone can even suggest a direction to go in that would be greatly appreciated.

Any questions you have I will try my best to answer.

Thanks for your time.

```
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    LogFileTracer tracer;

    // The search patterns
    Regex expdc = new Regex(@"Disconnected", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Regex expidle = new Regex(@"You will be kicked soon", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Regex expnospeeding = new Regex(@"?• ignored", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        tracer = new LogFileTracer();
        tracer.onTextReceived += Tracer_onTextReceived;
    }

    // Event if line was read from logfile
    private void Tracer_onTextReceived(string text)
    {
        try
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                // Thanks Microsoft for that threading bullcrap
                this.Invoke(new LogFileTracer.TextReceivedDelegate(Tracer_onTextReceived), text);
                return;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Nobody cares
        }

        if (text == null || text.Length == 0) return;

        // Check whether any of the patterns match
        if (expdc.IsMatch(text))
        {
            // play sound pattern
            txtEventLog.AppendText(text + "\r\n");
            Console.Beep(1000, 100);
            Console.Beep(750, 100);
            Console.Beep(500, 100);

        }
        else if (expidle.IsMatch(text))
        {
            // play sound pattern
            txtEventLog.AppendText(text + "\r\n");
            Console.Beep(2000, 50);
            Console.Beep(2050, 50);
            Console.Beep(2000, 50);

        }
        else if (expnospeeding.IsMatch(text))
        {
            // play sound pattern
            txtEventLog.AppendText(text + "\r\n");
            Console.Beep(1000, 50);
            Console.Beep(2050, 50);
            Console.Beep(2000, 50);

        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LblStatus.Text = "Logger Status: " + (tracer.isAlive ? "running" : "dead");

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Try to start the reader with the textbox
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtFilename.Text)) tracer.start(TxtFilename.Text);
    }

    private void CmdStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Start or restart the tracer
        tracer.start(TxtFilename.Text);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: The code looks like C# not VB. Also you haven't actually asked a question.  Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do but this `?• ignored` is not a valid regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a regex check for `mph•$`. This matches all the lines that end with `mph•`, but not those that include the `ignored`-keyword.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

If you're trying to parse for the following text

```
user ^Lclocked @ 138kph/ 86mph•
user ^Lclocked @ 63kph/ 39mph•^L ignored
```

Then I'd use a regex like this:

```
^user\s+\^Lclocked\s+@\s+([0-9]+)kph/\s*([0-9]+)mph[^\n\r]*
```

That regex will capture the data and put them into the capture groups like this:

- Group 0 gets the full string
- Group 1 gets the kph value
- Group 2 gets the mph value

Note: I'm using flags for multiline and case-insensitive.

**Sample Matches**

```
[0][0] = user ^Lclocked @ 138kph/ 86mph•
[0][1] = 138
[0][2] = 86

[1][0] = user ^Lclocked @ 63kph/ 39mph•^L ignored
[1][1] = 63
[1][2] = 39
```

## Explained

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  user                     'user'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \^                       '^'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Lclocked                 'Lclocked'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  @                        '@'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  kph/                     'kph/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  mph                      'mph'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\n\r]*                 any character except: '\n' (newline), '\r'
                           (carriage return) (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```